# cakephp url rewriting not working properly in the router file

Tags: cakephp

I am facing some problem with rewriting cakephp urls

Here is my url:

```
domain.com/users/members/mygroup
domain.com/users/admins/mygroup
```

I want to rewrite this to

```
domain.com/mygroup/members
domain.com/mygroup/admins
```

I have tried the following code but it's not working
In the routes.php i have created the following routes

```
Router::connect('/:groupname/:members', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members'),array('pass' => array('groupname')));

Router::connect('/:groupname/:admins', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admins'),array('pass' => array('groupname')));
```

Here is the links:

```
<?php echo $this->html->link('Members',array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'members','groupname'=>$groupdata['Group']['group_slug'],'members'=>members),array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'links','id'=>'memlink'));?>


<?php echo $this->html->link('Admin',array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'admins','groupname'=>$groupdata['Group']['group_slug'],'admins'=>admins),array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'links','id'=>'admnlink'));?>
```

When i create routes like this the first routing i.e member routing is working fine, but the second routing admin is not working, it's picking the members action and executing the members method but the url appears correct, only the action is wrong.

How can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Router::connect('/:groupname/:members', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members'),array('pass' => array('groupname', 'members')));

Router::connect('/:groupname/:admins', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admins'),array('pass' => array('groupname', 'admins')));
```

**Update**

```
Router::connect('/:groupname/:action', array('controller' => 'users'),array('pass' => array('groupname')));
Router::connect('/:groupname/:action', array('controller' => 'users'),array('pass' => array('groupname')));
```

working fine for me, put the code like this,

```
echo $this->html->link('Members',array(
    'controller'=>'users','action'=>'members',
    'groupname'=> 'mygroup'), array(
        'escape'=>false,'class'=>'links','id'=>'memlink'
));
 echo $this->html->link('Admin',array(
    'controller'=>'users','action'=>'admins',
    'groupname'=> 'mygroup'),array(
        'escape'=>false,
        'class'=>'links','id'=>'admnlink'
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, i tried this but not working, when i click on Admin link it's taking me to the members page.It's executing the first action in the router file, here member's action is the first in the routerfile. i am wondering why i'ts not checking the action.

Comment: Thanksss...I have tried this ,in this case it's considering the /:groupname as action, so its giving error MissingActionException. It is working well if i use like this **Router::connect('/users/:groupname/:action', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'members'),array('pass' => array('groupname')));**  But for me the controller name should not appear in the url

Comment: once check again my edits, if it's not working means your routes are effected by other routes you're setting..

Comment: my other routes are affected by this route

Comment: Check my update, if it's not working then Maybe the above route is effected by other routes you're setting.

Comment: your route is correct, but my other routes are affected by this.i need to check all other routes, thanks for the solution.